# Is it possible to auto populate a database with data

Tags: java, php, mysql

I was just wondering, is it possible to have a database that can be auto populated with specific data. For example, if you have a table consisting of electricity consumption and gas consumption, instead of me having to manually enter data of energy consumption, is there any way of this data being populated in the table periodically? Is such a thing possible?

Currently, my data is stored in phpmyAdmin.

Im asking because the project I'm working on requires data to be automatically populated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a program that populates the database with random data or specific data.

Answer (score 0):

If your energy consumption data is dependent on the gas and electricity consumption, you could always create a trigger in your database. Check out the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Then you could create a trigger on your gas and electricity tables so that when a record is inserted or updated, it automatically performs some other action, whether it be updating your energy consumption or something else.

Answer (score 0):

To auto generate data, almost of any kind, I would recommend `faker` https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker. Manual is fairly straightforward, I can point you to functions `randomFloat` to generate a fake amount of energy consumption.
If you need dates then whole `Faker\Provider\DateTime`, specifically `dateTimeBetween` or just `date`.

Then using it I would create a function which would add one row of random data. Run this function with cron job, and you can define how often, and how many random data would be inserted. Or don't use cron at all and just trigger insertion manually when you feel like needing more data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in other types of data, like the classical customer, product, sales type of tables, check out this [python project](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/populate_data) I created.

[image]